# send only field boxes filled. if empty then do not send in email. php form to email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I have this simple form to email in php. The nice thing about this form in the send php code is that I do NOT have to write out all the fields name.For example, I do NOT have to write this:

```
$msg .= "$_POST[ContactName]     Contact Name:     ContactName\n"
```

In my code, all I have to write is:

```
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
$body .= "$Field: $Value\n";
```

The form is currently working perfectly. It is currently sending this:

```
ContactName: name here
BusinessName: business name here
EmailAddress: email@email.com
Email_Confirmation: 
PhoneNumber: 714-555-5555
```

However, I wish this to happen: If a field is left empty or the web user does not fill it a certain field box, then the form should NOT send this field. For example: web user decides to NOT fill in ContactName and or BusinessName. So the form should only send this format:

```
EmailAddress: email@email.com
Email_Confirmation: 
PhoneNumber: 714-555-5555
```

Noticed no mention of ContactName: and BusinessName:

Please help! I would appreciate it. -Michelle Ha.

Here is the php send code:

```
if the Email_Confirmation field is empty
if(isset($_POST['Email_Confirmation']) && $_POST['Email_Confirmation'] == ''){

    // put your email address here
    $youremail = 'bomandty@gmail.com';

    // prepare a "pretty" version of the message
    $body .= "Thank you for your request. We will get back with you soon.";
    $body .= "\n";
    $body .= "\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
    $body .= "$Field: $Value\n"; 
    $body .= "\n";
    }

    $CCUser = $_POST['EmailAddress'];

    // Use the submitters email if they supplied one
    // (and it isn't trying to hack your form).
    // Otherwise send from your email address.
    if( $_POST['EmailAddress'] && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['EmailAddress']) ) {
      $headers = "From: $_POST[EmailAddress]";
    } else {
      $headers = "From: $youremail";
    }

    // finally, send the message
    mail($youremail, 'subject line here', $body, $headers, $CCUser );

}

// otherwise, let the spammer think that they got their message through
```

Comment: Use the empty() function? if(!empty($Value)){ //proceed with appending of message }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
if($Value != ''){
$body .= "$Field: $Value\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Now that ur code is working, great. Now, I have a new problem. Please have a look here: http://test4.bycustomdesign.com/order-form.shtml
Noticed I have a bunch of menu list drop down to select a different size, etc. The initial selection is always "Select". When I did a test send, it sends all fields. How do I modify the form code if user did not select anything or on default "Select" it will NOT send  in my email. The form will send but in the email, I will not get any fields with "Select"
Here is my code:
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { if($Value != ''){ $body .= "$Field: $Value\n";

Answer (score 1):

Add check to you foreach

```
if(empty($Value)) continue;
```

And change default falue in your form to placeholders