# php email form. Only want to post filled fields and not post empty ones

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a contact form that looks like [this](http://carine.zenwebcreative.com.au/contact.html)

Different form fields will appear based on what the user picks on the **"I would like to"** select box.

I want to implement a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987622/send-only-field-boxes-filled-if-empty-then-do-not-send-in-email-php-form-to-em) that I found on this site. Basically the php only posts fields that are filled out and does not post fields that are empty. It utilses the following code to achieve it

```
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
if($Value != ''){
$body .= "$Field: $Value\n";
}
}
```

I am not fluent in PHP and wasn't able to apply the solution proposed. Would appreciate if someone could help implement the solution into my code to make it post non empty form elements which includes text fields, select boxes and radio groups.

The code for my PHP form processor looks like the following

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];  
$email_address = $_POST['email'];  
$phone = $_POST['phone'];  
$message = $_POST['message'];  
$p_prefered_day = $_POST['p_prefered_day'];  (radio button)
$session_time = $_POST['session_time'];  (select box)
$p_message = $_POST['p_message'];  
$treatment = $_POST['treatment'];  (select box)
$therapist = $_POST['therapist'];  (select box)
$b_pref_day = $_POST['b_pref_day'];  (radio button)
$b_pref_time = $_POST['b_pref_time'];  (radio button)
$b_message = $_POST['b_message'];  

$to = 'info@zenwebcreative.com.au'; 
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nCompany: $company\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

The HTML code of my form looks like the following

```
  <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>                
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Full Name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div><!--  end form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email Address*</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div><!--  end form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Contact Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone">
    </div> <!-- end form group -->

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>I would like to *</label>
      <select id="select_question" class="form-control">            
        <option selected="selected">Please select</option>
        <option value="question">Ask a question</option>
        <option value="pilates">Attend a pilates class</option>
        <option value="booking">Schedule a booking</option>
      </select>
    </div><!--  end form-group --> 

    <div class="form-group box question">
    <label>Message</label>
      <div class="input-group">                  
        <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="7" required></textarea>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
      </div><!--  end input group -->
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div><!--  end form-group --> 

    <div class="box pilates">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Prefered day of the week *</label><br>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="p_prefered_day" id="Tue" value="Tuesday">Tuesday
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="p_prefered_day" id="Thu" value="Thursday">Thursday
        </label>
      </div> <!-- end form group -->

      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Prefered Session you would like to attend? *</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="session_time">
          <option value="4:30 pm">4:30 pm</option>
          <option value="5:30 pm">5:30 pm</option>
          <option value="6:30 pm">6:30 pm</option>
        </select>
      </div><!--  end form-group --> 

      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Additional Comments</label>
        <div class="input-group">                  
          <textarea id="p_message" class="form-control" rows="7" required></textarea>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
        </div><!--  end input group -->
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div><!--  end form-group --> 

    </div><!--  end box pilates -->

    <div class="box booking">

      <div class="form-group">
      <label>What Service Are You Interested In? *</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="services">
          <option value="Manual Therapy">Manual Therapy</option>
          <option value="Sports Physiotherapy">Sports Physiotherapy</option>
          <option value="Dry Needling">Dry Needling</option>
          <option value="Post and Pre operative care">Post and Pre operative care</option>
          <option value="Real Time Ultrasound Imaging">Real Time Ultrasound Imaging</option>
          <option value="Balance and Vestibular treatment">Balance and Vestibular treatment</option>
          <option value="Sports Specific Rehabilitation">Sports Specific Rehabilitation</option>
          <option value="Motor Vehicle Accident">Motor Vehicle Accident</option>
          <option value="Workers Compensation">Workers Compensation</option>            
        </select>
      </div><!--  end form-group --> 

      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Which therapist would you like to see*</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="therapist">
          <option selected="selected">No Preference</option>
          <option value="Kristen">Kristen</option>
          <option value="Tara">Tara</option>        
        </select>
      </div><!--  end form-group --> 

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Prefered day of the week *</label><br>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="b_pref_day" id="b_Mon" value="Mon-">Mon
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="b_pref_day" id="b_Tue" value="Tue">Tue
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="b_pref_day" id="b_Wed" value="Wed">Wed
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="b_pref_day" id="b_Thu" value="Thu">Thu
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="b_pref_day" id="b_Fri" value="Fri">Fri
        </label>
      </div> <!-- end form group --> 

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Prefered time of the day</label><br>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="b_pref_time" id="morning" value="Morning">Morning
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="b_pref_time" id="afternoon" value="Afternoon">Afternoon
        </label>
      </div> <!-- end form group --> 

      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Addtional Comments</label>
        <div class="input-group">                  
          <textarea id="b_message" class="form-control" rows="7" required></textarea>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
        </div><!--  end input group -->
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div><!--  end form-group --> 

   </div> <!-- end box booking -->

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div id="success"></div>
    <button id="send_btn" type="submit" class="btn cpcbutton">Send Message</button>
    <p class="help-block"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk green"></span> Required Fields </p>
  </form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The PHP itself doesn't post a thing. Are you trying to change what gets posted to PHP through the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$body = "";
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
    if($Value != ''){
        $body .= "$Field: $Value\n\n";
    }
}

$to = 'info@zenwebcreative.com.au'; 
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details: $body";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
```

I replaced all the code that assigns variables from the $_POST array to the snippet you provided. That basically do the same thing that your previous code was doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does work in returning text fields but I also have select boxes and radio buttons with values that aren't being posted. Can your code account for those element types? Apologies in advance if my question was not specific enough.

Comment: 1.) This will print all posted values without exception--it you are not seeing it then something else is wrong.    2.) Many of your form element are missing the name attribute, which is a requirement for being picked up by the POST array.

Comment: Hi. I tried inserting names to the select box and radio group but the form is still only returning the name,email and message fields only. I guess something is wrong but am not able to identify where or what. Thanks for trying anyway

Comment: This answer addresses the original question--please accept an answer. I'd then suggest you create another question for the separate issue of the form fields not coming in.

Comment: I found out what was wrong on my end but your solution was correct and fixed my issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach`-loop is working as is, but the code looks a bit cleaner when using `empty()` instead, like this (but the one you have already does the same job!):

```
foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) { 
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $body .= "$field: $value\n\n";
    }
}
```

This assigns all the variables in the global `$_POST`-array that is not empty into the `$body`-variable. Using this, you don't need the other `$_POST` statements (for example `$message = $_POST['message'];`). The only problem with this is that ALL your content from the `$_POST`-array is printed (even the submit-buttons value!).

Then you just put that in your `mail`-function like this:

```
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n";
$email_body .= "Here are the details:\n\n";
$email_body .= "$body";
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
```

Another alternative is to check every field explicitly, although this will generate a lot more code.

```
if (!empty($_POST['name']))
    $body .= "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n\n";
if (!empty($_POST['email']))
    $body .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']."\n\n";
if (!empty($_POST['phone']))
    $body .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."\n\n";
```

Same deal here with how you can add it to your mail-function.

There are of course other ways of doing things, and out of the two, I'd recommend the `foreach`-loop, as it's much less and cleaner code, that should do the same job. If it prints the "submit" values too, you can just add a piece of code that skips that element of the global `$_POST` array.

---

You should have a statement that prevents the script to be run every time someone visits this page directly, like having a `if ($_POST['submit'] == 'submit')` (where `submit` are the name and value of your submit-button in the HTML form) statement that wraps all your mail-relevant code. This way, mails are only sent after the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned to dlporter98 above, your code  works in returning text fields but does not post select boxes and radio buttons with values. Can you modify your code to account for those element types? Apologies in advance if my question was not specific enough to begin with.

Comment: Hi Qirel. I actually implemented your code instead of dlporters above even though I selected his answer. Both of your codes are essentially the same and work correctly but i prefer the way you laid out your code. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should create a whitelist array of your accepted keys:

```
$whitelist = array('name', 'email', 'phone');
```

And then loop through the array as follows:

```
foreach($whitelist as $key){
  if(isset($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key] != ''){
    $body .= ucfirst($key) . ": " . htmlspecialchars($_POST[$key], ENT_QUOTES) . "\n";
  }
}
```

`foreach` loops through the array, `isset` checks that the field is set, `ucfirst` makes the key look presentable in the email by capitalizing the first character, and `htmlspecialchars` with the `ENT_QUOTES` flag ensures the characters are properly converted for the email.

You should always create a whitelist for this type of loop, not only for security purposes but also because you'll be looping through unnecessary or irrelevant keys, such as:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="1">Submit</button>
```

Your email will then see:

```
Submit: 1
```

Which makes no sense to the recipient.